# Insert a table in word between two tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with tables containing hyperlinks to other word documents, see image below. The word documents are catogorized into groups, i.e 1 table for each group.

[image: tables]

My problem is that sometimes people messes around with the formatting, such as adding a newline or removing a newline between the tables(so it becomes 1,2,3,4 newlines instead of 2 as my code requires) or change the order to not be alphabetic(rare and I can live with that).

So finally to my problem, In this case I created a new document PL_xxxx and the table PL does not exist, so it should insert a new table, but with SINGLE newline between tables  this get inserted inside another table instead of in between tables.

```
' Now move up two lines, beyond the table end
                Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
```

So how can I either ensure that it is always consistence newlines between tables? Is there a way to remove all newlines between tables and then recreate them, and then do the table insert? Or can I somehow loop through all tables in documents? Or is there some other way to make sure that mistakes not like this happens?

So here is my main code:

```
'here we alter the docout tables
If Not searchAll(dokType) Then
    Call addList(dokType, Settings.documentTypeFile)
    docNumber = "01"
Else
```

Below is my code that seach if PL exist, which will return false in this case:

```
' Moves cursor to the place the given string is found, or replace it
  Function searchAll(searchText As String, Optional replaceText As String = "GGG") As Boolean
    'default false
    searchAll = False


    If Not replaceText = "GGG" Then

        With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
             .Text = searchText
             .forward = True
             .Wrap = wdFindContinue
             .Format = True
             .MatchCase = True
             .MatchWholeWord = True
            .Replacement.Text = replaceText
            If .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll) Then
                searchAll = True
            End If
        End With
    'just searching
    Else
         With Selection.Find
             .Text = searchText
             .forward = True
             .Wrap = wdFindContinue
             .Format = True
             .MatchCase = True
             .MatchWholeWord = True
             If .Execute Then
                searchAll = True
            End If
        End With
    End If


End Function
```

Here is the code that actually figures out where to place the table and add its, and here is the problem(rewrite to loop through tables instead or modify the moveup function)

```
 Sub addList(tableKey As String, filenameTypes As String)
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim addAtEnd As Boolean
    Dim keyArray As Variant
    Dim startSearching As Boolean
    Dim element As Variant
    'Dictionary with all types
    Set dict = getTypes(filenameTypes)

   With dict
   addAtEnd = False
    'extract keys into variant array
    keyArray = .keys
    startSearching = False
    For Each element In keyArray
          'looping untill we find the element we want to add
          If element = tableKey Then
            startSearching = True
           End If


        'Finding the next table after were we want to insert
        If startSearching Then
              If searchAll(CStr(element)) Then
                  addAtEnd = False
                  Exit For
              Else
                  addAtEnd = True
              End If
        End If

    Next

    If addAtEnd Then
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Else
        Call HelpFunctions.moveCursorUp(CStr(element))
    End If

    Call addTable("UT", tableKey, .item(tableKey), Settings.docUtPath)

    End With

    Set dict = Nothing


 End Sub
```

And finally the move up function which then obviously moves up to much and inside the next table.

```
'move cursor up
  Function moveCursorUp(searchText As String)

    If Not searchAll(searchText) Then
        MsgBox "Failed to move cursor"
    Else
         'Selection.Tables(1).Select

        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Tables(1).Range.Select
            Selection.Collapse 1

            ' Now move up two lines, beyond the table end
            Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
        End If
        'Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
    End If

  End Function
```

And here is the addtable code which basically has an empty tabley stored in a seperate file.

```
  Function addTable(typeOfTable As String, category As String, description As String, templateFolder As String)
        'Insert out table
        If UCase(typeOfTable) = "UT" Then
            Selection.InsertFile FileName:=templateFolder + "\Doklistut.doc", Range:="", _
            ConfirmConversions:=False, link:=False, Attachment:=False
        'insert inn table
        ElseIf UCase(typeOfTable) = "INN" Then
            Selection.InsertFile FileName:=templateFolder + "\Doklistinn.doc", Range:="", _
            ConfirmConversions:=False, link:=False, Attachment:=False
        Else
            MsgBox "wrong argument given: either inn or ut is allowed"
            Exit Function
        End If

        'Replace the DT with the category
         If Not searchAll("DT", category) Then
             MsgBox "Failed to replace category in table"
         End If

          'Replace the Dokumenttype with the category
         If Not searchAll("Dokumenttype", description) Then
             MsgBox "Failed to replace document type in table"
         End If
  End Function
```

Comment: Mmm, you show us code that has nothing to do with manipulating the tables, but not the code that does work with the tables. AddTable is missing, for example, that your code "calls".  No idea what "tableKey" is... And one really huge problem with what you want to do is that you use Selection instead of objects, such as Range and Table. The one thing I can tell you is that you MUST have at least one paragraph mark between tables, otherwise Word will combine two tables into one table - and you don't want that.

Comment: To be consistent, I'd make sure there's ONE and only one paragraph between tables. If you visually want more space, format the paragraph with SpaceBefore or SpaceAfter (use STYLES!). And, yes, it's possible to loop through tables in a document, but since you don't show us any of the code that works with tables, that's all that can be said.

Comment: FWIW (a) I agree with Cindy Meister's comments but (b) the real question IMO is how much control you have over what the users do. *If* you have a lot of control, and your users are all using recent versions of Windows Word, perhaps one way to ensure that you have a particular, identifiable kind of gap between tables would be to insert a non-deletable Content control between them. The user might accidentally add extra space between the tables, but it would be harder to delete the control. etc....

Comment: So sorry that I forgot the addtable code, I edit the originally post now. I am working on rewriting to use object now as suggested. Will post my progress shortly:)

Comment: and where is the problem in running your current code?

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to all the input I have now revised the code totally and it is now working as desired, It can probably be improved, especially the selection method.

```
Sub addList(tableKey As String, tableDescription As String)
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Call addTable(tableKey, tableDescription)
    Call SortTables
 End Sub

Sub Deleemptylines()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub

Sub SortTables()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iMin As Long
    Dim iMax As Long
    Dim blnSwapped As Boolean

    Call Deleemptylines
    iMin = 1
    iMax = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count - 1

    Do
        blnSwapped = False
        For i = iMin To iMax

          If ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text > ActiveDocument.Tables(i + 1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text Then

                ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Range.Cut

                ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Select
                Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
                Selection.Paragraphs.Add
                Selection.Paragraphs.Add
                Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
                Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
                Selection.Paste
                blnSwapped = True
            End If
        Next i
        iMax = iMax - 1
    Loop Until Not blnSwapped

    Call Deleemptylines
End Sub


  Function addTable(category As String, description As String)
        'Insert out table
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:=Settings.docUtPath + "\Doklistut.doc", Range:="", _
        ConfirmConversions:=False, link:=False, Attachment:=False

        'Replace the DT with the category
         If Not searchAll("DT", category) Then
             MsgBox "Failed to replace category in table"
         End If

        'Replace the Dokumenttype with the category
         If Not searchAll("Dokumenttype", description) Then
             MsgBox "Failed to replace document type in table"
         End If
  End Function
```